# Issue With Leading Zero While export datagrid to excel

Tags: asp.net

I am Binding DataGrid From Database and Trying to export it to Excel but i am  getting issue with leading Zero from First column , which contain a Policy Numbers,suppose  in database policy no. is '012345678' ,but when i export it to excel then it showing '12345678'

My Code is Below:

```
public static void ToExcelWithHeader(DataSet dsInput, string filename,HttpResponse response, string HeaderPart, DataTable dt, string Url = "")
{
    DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
    dg.DataSource = dsInput.Tables[0];
    dg.DataBind();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Buffer = true;

    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    System.IO.StringWriter objSW = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter objHTW = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(objSW);

    dg.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;     // SET EXCEL HEADERS AS BOLD.

     //STYLE THE SHEET AND WRITE DATA TO IT.
    response.Write("<style>");
    response.Write("TABLE { border:dotted 1px #999; }");
    response.Write("TD { border:dotted 1px #D5D5D5; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; }");
    response.Write(".table { background-color: yellow; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; }");
    response.Write("</style>");

    response.Write(HeaderPart);

    response.Write(objSW.ToString());
    if (Url != "")
        response.AddHeader("Refresh", "3; url=" + Url);
    response.End();


    dg = null;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: You need to explicitly tell Excel that the column contains strings, rather than numbers. If Excel sees a string of digits, it will automatically remove all leading zeroes, unless it is told that the digits are actually part of a string. Debug your code to find out exactly where the leading zero is being lost. That should help you solve the issue.

Comment: This code never compiles(for instance, where is the `try` of the `catch`). Where is the real code? Please try to format your code better next time. You can use the editor and the code-button there.

Comment: Can u please tell Me how to set a Textmode="Text" of particular cell of datagrid in asp.net